# "Burning" the result of a #define

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, compiler-directives

Suppose a define like this

```
#define myDate [NSDate date]
```

every time I use it, it gives me the current date, what is ok.

What I want is to store the date the code was compiled. Can I do that with defines or using any other way?

I want the date to be hard stored in the code.

Ok I know I can store the date as string, this is not what I want.

Comment: "Ok I know I can store the date as string" – then you can convert that string to an `NSDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC has predefined macros for this. Check out `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Also, you can define your own key like `CFBuildDate` and increment it with a script : [Xcode project's "Build number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371345/xcode-projects-build-number)